# What is "Inference daemon"?

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

When building project on CircleCI, during Infrastructure phase:

```
Starting the build
Installing inference daemon...
Inference daemon installed.
Starting inference daemon...
Inference daemon started.
```

What is the mysterious *inference daemon*?

Answer (score 2):

From the name I believe that it's an internal tool they use to calculate which inferences they should make based on your code in order to automatically setup as much as possible of the infrastructure so you don't have to.

In any case it's certainly an internal tool, so you should write them and ask :)